# What is the benefit of using ParamArray (vs a Variant array)?

Tags: vba, vb6

I've used the `ParamArray` statement for years when I wanted to accept a variable number of arguments.  One good example is this MinVal function:

```
Function MinVal(ParamArray Values() As Variant)
    Dim ReturnVal As Variant, v As Variant

    If UBound(Values) < 0 Then
        ReturnVal = Null
    Else
        ReturnVal = Values(0)
        For Each v In Values
            If v < ReturnVal Then ReturnVal = v
        Next v
    End If
    MinVal = ReturnVal

End Function
' Debug.Print MinVal(10, 23, 4, 17)
' 4
```

This could be re-written without the ParamArray as:

```
Function MinVal(Optional Values As Variant)
    Dim ReturnVal As Variant, v As Variant

    If IsMissing(Values) Or IsNull(Values) Then
        ReturnVal = Null
    Else
        ReturnVal = Values(0)
        For Each v In Values
            If v < ReturnVal Then ReturnVal = v
        Next v
    End If
    MinVal = ReturnVal

End Function
' Debug.Print MinVal(Array(10, 23, 4, 17))
' 4
```

Note in the second example use of the `Array()` function in the call to MinVal.

The second approach has the advantage of being able to pass the parameter array to another function that also accepts arrays.  This provides flexibility if I ever wanted to be able to pass the parameter array in `MinVal` on to some other function.

I've begun thinking I should *always* favor this approach and just stop using `ParamArray` altogether.

One could argue that using `ParamArray` makes for more explicitly readable code.  However, there's no advantage in compile-time checks because `ParamArray` *must* be an array of Variants.  **Can anyone offer a compelling reason to *ever* use `ParamArray`?**

Comment: `Array` function returns array of `Variant`s too -- and you can't cast it to array of `Long`s as is.

Answer (score 3):

Most of my `ParamArray` functions have std `Array` versions that do the heavy lifting like this:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Process 1, 2, 3
End Sub

Private Sub Process(ParamArray A() As Variant)
    ProcessArray CVar(A)
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessArray(B As Variant)
    Debug.Print UBound(B)
End Sub
```

This does not work for output params though, so yes replacing `ParamArray` with `Array` gets really fast very inconvenient for output params.

Comment: I also do that - have an "array" version that can be called directly, and sometimes a `ParamArray` version that delegates to the "array" version. Also, I never knew that `ParamArray` parameters were essentially passed `ByRef`. While I think using elements of a `ParamArray` as output parameters is likely to be very dangerous, it's nice to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

You've already noted one reason to use `Paramarray` - sometimes it makes code more clear. In fact, I think in your own example that:

```
Debug.Print MinVal(10, 23, 4, 17)
```

is preferable to:

```
Debug.Print MinVal(Array(10, 23, 4, 17))
```

Of course, how "compelling" this is is a matter of opinion. Code clarity rarely matters much in small examples, but in a large code base it can add up to be very important.

If you're using VBA with Excel, then there *is* a somewhat-compelling reason to use `ParamArray`. Consider a UDF of the following form:

```
Public Function mungeRanges(ParamArray ranges())
    'do something with a bunch of ranges
End Function
```

The built-in Excel function `MIN` works like this in fact - you can pass in multiple arguments, including ranges or arrays, and it looks through all of them to find the smallest individual value. Anything that follows a similar pattern would need to use `ParamArray`.