# Unpacking Array into ParamArray in VBA

Tags: vba, paramarray

Given an array of unknown size and a procedure that accepts a Parameter Array, how can one pass the array as the parameter array without modifying the procedure?

```
Sub Example(sequence() As String)
    UnModifiableSub sequence
End Sub

Sub UnModifiableSub(ParamArray bar())
    ' bar(0) = sequence not bar = sequence
End Sub
```

I'm looking behavior similar to Python's unpacking

```
def foo(*args):  # identical to ParamArray
    print(args)

x = [1,2,3,4]
foo(*x)  # what VBA can't do
```

I know there is no built-in solution like there is in Python but any cruel implementation is acceptable other than a long switch statement.

Comment: Does `UnModifiableSub Array(sequence)` do the trick?

Comment: No that nests it further. Then `bar(0)(0) = sequence`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The giant switch statement sounds kind of cruel to me, but that's what you're in for if the routine you must call is truly unmodifiable. In VBA, that's a `Select Case` statement. And don't forget that VBA arrays can have arbitrary indices, so you have to test both `LBound` and `UBound` unless you're sure where your sequence argument is coming from.

*If* you can write your own routine, there is a a way to mostly do what you want. You can assign an array to a variable of type `Variant`, like so:

```
Sub tryThis(v)
    Debug.Assert IsArray(v)
    Debug.Print v(LBound(v))
End Sub

Sub Example(sequence() As String)
    tryThis sequence
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim s() As String

    ReDim s(1 To 2)
    s(1) = "a"
    s(2) = "b"

    Call Example(s)
End Sub
```

`tryThis()` takes the place of your `UnModifiableSub`. If you run `test()` in the Immediate window you get this output:

```
call test
a
```

I think that's the behavior you want. (Somewhat, anyway. Nobody wants arbitrary array indices.) Of course, this is limited compared to Python. Notably, if you want to call `tryThis()`, you must put your "parameters" into an array yourself. Some of the tradeoffs related to doing that are discussed in this answer and the parent question:

[What is the benefit of using ParamArray (vs a Variant array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465107/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-paramarray-vs-a-variant-array/22583986#22583986)

There are some other issues as well. For example, you can't just pass the contents of a `ParamArray` to `tryThis()`:

```
'Doesn't work...
Sub gotcha(ParamArray pa())

    'Can't do it this way! "Invalid ParamArray use"
    Call tryThis(pa)
End Sub
```

You have to make the transfer to a variable explicitly:

```
Sub gotchaFixed(ParamArray pa())
    Dim v
    v = pa

    Call tryThis(v)
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Call gotchaFixed("a", "b")
End Sub
```

...

```
call test2
a
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible to pass an argument *as* the `ParamArray`, by its nature you are not assigning *to* the `ParamArray` itself, but mapping to elements *of* the `ParamArray`.

> Each argument passed by the caller maps to an element in the ParamArray variable.  Consequently, the ParamArray variable will have as many elements as the arguments passed by the calling statement.

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml